# Vue CDN of html working but v-if not working

Tags: vue.js

I'm using a [CDN](https://unpkg.com/vue) to run some vue code in my `index.html`. I'm just learning from a tutorial and this is my first time I use vue.

This is `index.html`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>THE TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{ greeting }}
    <input v-model="greeting"/> <hr />
  </div>
  <div v-if="isVisible" class="box"></div>

  <script src='https://unpkg.com/vue'></script>
  <script src="vue.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is `vue.js`

```js
let app = Vue.createApp({
  data: function() {
    return {
      greeting: "Hello vue3!",
      isVisible: false
    }
  }
});
app.mount("#app");
```

I am sure that vue cdn is working because v-model is working properly, but somehow v-if is not.
Also i asked chatGPT and it said I'm not importing CDN properly and edited my `vue.js` file completely.

Comment: v-if is outside #app

Comment: Why U used just a comment? This is the answer. Thank you so much

Comment: Sure, glad the solution was that simple

Comment: Yes it took me 3 days and even chatGPT didn't give me true answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-if` is outside `#app`. It should be:

```
  <div id="app">
    {{ greeting }}
    <input v-model="greeting"/> <hr />
    <div v-if="isVisible" class="box"></div>
  </div>
```